# Why can I not set innerHtml of an iframe body in firefox?

Tags: firefox, iframe, internals

Say you have an iframe and you are modifying its contentDocument with javascript.

Theoretically you can do this by either setting the `contentDocument.body.innerHTML` directly or using `contentDocument.write()`

[See this example on jsbin](http://jsbin.com/ekoreb/1/edit)

In chrome both work just fine. In firefox however the top one flashes in and out. (In IE10 the top one throws an error with the body being null but I'm not worried about IE).

Two questions:

- Why does this happen in firefox?
- Which behavior is the "correct" one according to the spec?

Comment: I'm going to go with not injecting content into an iframe as a viable solution.

Comment: @Leeish - solution to what? There's lots of good reasons you might want to inject content. Heck, there's even a part of the html5 spec all about it (sandbox, srcdoc, seamless attributes)

Comment: I apologize, I've never come across a reason to inject content into an iframe that couldn't be solved another way.

Comment: @leeish it comes up a mostly when you want to give users scripting ability but only over their own content. An example is jsbin itself. In my case I have an in-browser IDE that can be used to build html reports

Comment: I usually hear it come up when people have the question of, I have an iFrame from page x which I don't control. How do I change css/javascript etc into that iframe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Firefox, when you create an iframe it starts loading `about:blank`.  Then your script races with that load: you modify the DOM, and then about:blank loads and wipes out your changes.

"The spec" doesn't define the behavior here so far (like most of document loading), though there's a proposal in webapps that would do so.  That proposal would be that there should be no about:blank load in this situation and instead a fake load event should get fired even though no load happened (because websites depend on frames with no src firing load events).

Comment: Interesting. Not at my pc now but does that mean I can schedule the update after the iframe document's load event and it will work? Why does the doc.open() form stick?

Comment: Hmm, [according to Remy from jsbin](https://twitter.com/rem/status/305272817686036480) open/close ensures the doc's ready events get fired though I can't quite seem to get a load event no matter what: http://jsbin.com/ekoreb/5/edit

Comment: `doc.open` cancels any pending loads, and in particular cancels the `about:blank` load.